Remote Work for a German Employer While Residing in the Netherlands: Do I Need Additional Permits and a German Address?
My situation is as follows:

I do not have the nationality of an EU/EEA country or Switzerland.
I live in the Netherlands with my partner, who is an EU citizen and works in the Netherlands.
I have obtained a Dutch residence permit (as a family member of an EU citizen).

Recently, I was offered a job in Germany. The job is remote and only requires me to travel to Germany for one or two days per month.
I would like to know:

Am I legally allowed to stay in the Netherlands and work remotely in Germany?
Will I need to apply for a German residence permit (in addition to my Dutch one)?
Do I need a German address?


What does the employment contract say? Isn’t the point of remote working that it does not require ongoing physical presence in a given location? In which case, why would you need German residency or a German address?

@Traveller It's complicated, many legal systems and HR processes require specifying a place of work (and have additional obligations for work that's inherently nomadic: salespeople, truck drivers, maintenance or installation technicians). This is important for tax and insurance reasons but goes beyond this. For example, the employer may have an obligation to ensure their employees have a safe workplace with a proper office desk and chair for office-based work, etc.

Consequently, all my remote contracts have specified an address where I was supposed to work, typically my home address. In some cases there was an explicit rule on how often and how long I was allowed to work elsewhere, in others an informal understanding that they did not care at all but still pretended that it would be my workplace.


Am I legally allowed to stay in the Netherlands and work remotely in Germany?

You would actually be working remotely in the Netherlands. That's very simple and perfectly fine.
The fact that it's for a German company creates some issues (more on that later) but from a work permit / immigration point of view, it's a distraction, you are simply working in the country for which you have a permit.
Unlike some other Dutch permits (kennismigrant, EU Blue card), there is no limitation on the type of work allowed for members of the family of an EU citizen so no need for the employer to be registered, pay a fee, or anything like that either.

Will I need to apply for a German residence permit (in addition to my Dutch one)?

No, for the same reason: You do not need a German permit to work in the Netherlands.

Do I need a German address?

That's where things become complicated. Your employer needs a way to deal with all the usual HR processes, satisfy their own obligations, mandatory insurances, tax withholding, etc. Since you would physically be in the Netherlands when working then all the Dutch rules on taxes, insurances, bank holidays, leave, workplace safety, etc. in principle apply to you.
Giving your employer a German address might allow them to pretend you are in Germany but it won't solve the underlying issue as it doesn't change the fact that you would in principle be subject to Dutch law if you don't reside in Germany. Crucially, registering a German address as your main residence would imply and require that you actually live there and among other things getting a German residence permit.
Outside of very specific circumstances (like posted workers and cross-border workers), it's quite complicated to deal with all that across borders and most employers are not prepared to do it. Businesses that regularly hire remote workers are however familiar with the issues and can typically specify early in the process in what jurisdictions they hire and how. Sometimes they even state it explicitly in job postings or on their “careers” website.
If your employer is aware that you would be working from the Netherlands or already hired other people based there, they probably have a solution in mind, e.g. hiring you through a Dutch subsidiary or a third-party company. Otherwise, you need to approach them as soon as possible to clarify that you do not intend to reside in Germany. Be prepared for the fact that they may not be able or willing to hire you, even if the job is remote and in the same timezone.
Note that all these issues are mostly unrelated to the residence permit / immigration question and would also exist if you were a German citizen, a Dutch citizen, or a citizen from another EU country. So if you are getting questions or sensing confusion from the HR department at your prospective employer, you can ask them if they have ever done it for an EU citizen and explain that you are in the exact same situation. You just need them to figure out the tax / labor law issues but thanks to your status as the partner of an EU citizen, you do not need their help regarding work permits or immigration.
